# xlsx File is corrupted on download in php

Tags: php, excel, zend-framework

I need to download xlsx file in php. The file is downloading but when i open it shows as corrupted file. I used zend Framework

**Controller:**

```
$fullPath = '/opt/bitnami/lampstack-5.4.36-0/apps/projects/ProjectName/File_Name.xlsx';

 if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) 
 {
   $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
   $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
   $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);             

   header("Content-type: application/xlsx");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
   header("Content-length: $fsize");
   header("Cache-control: private");

   while(!feof($fd)) 
   {
     $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
     echo $buffer;//To display the file content while downloaded.
    }
   }
   fclose ($fd);
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo $this->buffer; ?>
```

Other than xlsx/xls file is downloading correctly(PDF/any image file).

Comment: Try unlocking it from properties..

Comment: Try to increase the buffer size to 4096

Comment: I have full rights to file(read/write and execute). -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: @liswectec Increased buffer size. That too not worked

Comment: What's the exact error message from Excel?  Is the file you're downloading an actual xlsx file, or something else pretending to be an Excel file?

Comment: @TimWilliams xlsx/xls file is downloaded. But when i try to open it ask for delimeter(Libreoffice calc). When i open source xlsx file, it opening properly doesn't ask any delimeter.

Comment: @Deepak Have you opened the downloaded file in an editor and looked at the actual contents? PHP messages inside, perhaps? Or just some extraneous linefeed? You can open an xlsx that you know works beside it to compare file headers.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo I opened downloaded file in editor and all word are shown in corrupt format(mixer of heart symbol with question marks and some unwanted symbols)

Comment: @Deepak That is to be expected, after all it's not exactly a pure text file :). But if you look at the *header* of the file? Does it look the same as the header of an xlsx file that you know works/can be loaded? Are the first 2 characters in the file 'PK' for example(no linefeeds or anything before it)? Do you see *any* differences in format?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo First row of first column start with PK followed by mixer of diamnod symbol and question mark and Gxl/worksheets/sheet1.xml

Comment: @Deepak Can you run a program to compare the downloaded xlsx with the source file(the xlsx on your server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I cut and paste the code in separate controller which having downloading code only. In that time it works.

It is caused because of error occur in init function(Mapping needed controller and model files). Comment each file and check and found error in one file.

Hope this answer will help someone

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems than can occur and lead to this error.

First thing to do is probably to set header like this :

`header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('./uploads/resources/courses/' . $filename));`

and

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Just to be sure this is neither a header nor a filesire problem.

Often with xlsx file you'll have a BOM at the begining of the file.
There is a very easy way to test out if it is the problem using unzip.
Try to unzip your xlsx file and if you have something like this then this is the BOM causing the problem.

```
unzip -l your-file.xlsx
```

You should see

```
warning file:  3 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile.
```

You can also check with the hex viewer

```
head -c5 your-file.xlsx | xxd -g 1
```

If you have an output like this :

```
 0000000: ef bb bf 50 4b
```

Then it's a BOM problem (notice the 3 first byte `ef` `bb` `bf`).

Removing the bom (internet is full of solution for this), or encoding the file to UTF-8 should do the trick.

Hope it helped ya.

Comment: I added header in my file and downloaaded but still it not works. I execute the unzip command, it doesn't show any warning. hex viewer command shows output as 0000000: 50 4b 03 04 14         PK...

Comment: @Deepak same issue here. How did you fix it?